# How can I access the text inside of a Text component?

Tags: react-native

Given something like this:

```
<Text>Hello</Text>
```

Is there any way to access the text inside this Component?

Here is a specific example where I would like to connect the text inside a Text component to the press of a TouchableOpacity. The deletekey function in this example needs to get "Hello" as a parameter.

```
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteKey()}>
                        <EvilIcon
                            name='close'
                            type='evilicon'
                            color='#517fa4'
                            size={15}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ref` of `Text`

```
<Text ref='helloText'>Hello</Text>
```

and `onPress` of `TouchableOpacity`

```
this.refs.helloText.props.children
```

If you have dynamic text inside `<Text>` you should use `state`

```
<Text>{this.state.textValue}</Text>
```

and to set value in it, you need to use `this.setState({textValue:'Hello'})`

Comment: Oh, aweseome! I'm a bit confused though by how you access the ref on press. If the ref='helloText', why is that inside onPress I don't access like this.refs.helloText.props.children?

Comment: Yes, i have updated answer, actualy i have copied it from my project so :D